# Copying local file to network shared drive issues

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using the code below to check if a directory on a network drive exists. If it does I copy the file; if not I create the directory and then copy it over.  However I am having issues.  Any help would be appreciated thanks.  The main issues is an IO exception with the message the network name cannot be found.  Also my savelocation variable looks like if the slashes are not being escaped.

```
string savelocation = @"\\network\" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "\\" +
    comboBox2.SelectedItem+"\\"+Environment.UserName;

// When I check what savelocation is, it returns the unescaped string
// for example \\\\network\\ and so on

if (Directory.Exists(savelocation)) // this returns true even if it exists
{
    File.Copy(@"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\test\" + label5.Text,
        savelocation + "\\" + label5.Text);
}
else {
    DirectoryInfo d = Directory.CreateDirectory(savelocation);
    // The line above says the network name cannot be found

    File.Copy(@"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\test\" + label5.Text,
        "\\\\atlanta2-0\\it-documents\\filestroage\\" + comboBox1.SelectedItem +
        "\\" + comboBox2.SelectedItem + "\\" + Environment.UserName + label5.Text);
}
```

Comment: sure, as soon as you tell us what the issue are exactly...

Comment: Can you browse to `\\network` using Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, let's work on this code a little. First let's simplify building the paths. We have a network path **and** a local path. According to your current code the network path is built with a few variables `comboBox1`, `comboBox2`, and `Environment.UserName`, so let's do it a little different:

```
var networkPath = Path.Combine(@"\\network",
    comboBox1.SelectedItem as string,
    comboBox2.SelectedItem as string,
    Environment.UserName);
```

that's going to place the `\` in between each of those strings properly (i.e. if there were already a back slash it wouldn't add one, but would if necessary).

Now let's do the same for the local path:

```
var localPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users",
    Environment.UserName,
    "test",
    label5.Text);
```

ok, we're almost there, but we also have an alternative network path:

```
var alternativeNetworkPath = Path.Combine(@"\\atlanta2-0\it-documents\filestroage",
    comboBox1.SelectedItem as string,
    comboBox2.SelectedItem as string,
    Environment.UserName,
    label5.Text);
```

now, one thing about this path that's already suspect to me is this, `\filestroage`, that's actually spelled wrong. Now, if the folder is spelled that way fine, but I'm wondering if it's spelled wrong. So just take a look. Alright, let's continue on, now we have all three paths built, it's a little easier to read, and we can easily output those strings to **ensure** they are right. Let's take a look at the logic. It says this, **if the `networkPath` exists then save it there**, however, **if it does not exist then create it and save it to the `alternativeNetworkPath`.** So let's do that:

```
if (Directory.Exists(networkPath))
{
    File.Copy(localPath, networkPath);
}
else
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(networkPath);
    File.Copy(localPath, alternativeNetworkPath);
}
```

alright, simple enough yes? But you stated that the `Directory.Exists` is returning true `even if it exists`. That's pretty much expected isn't it? If the directory exists then this method would certainly return `true`, if not then it would return `false`. You then stated with the `Directory.CreateDirectory` that `The line above says the network name cannot be found` - **that can only mean that the path was constructed wrong.**

So after breaking it down, the bottom line is this, the paths being constructed have to be off a tidge. However, with this new model you should be able to pull those paths out ***a lot easier.*** So the entire method, in my mind, would look something like this:

```
var networkPath = Path.Combine(@"\\network",
    comboBox1.SelectedItem as string,
    comboBox2.SelectedItem as string,
    Environment.UserName);

var localPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users",
    Environment.UserName,
    "test",
    label5.Text);

var alternativeNetworkPath = Path.Combine(@"\\atlanta2-0\it-documents\filestroage",
    comboBox1.SelectedItem as string,
    comboBox2.SelectedItem as string,
    Environment.UserName,
    label5.Text);

if (Directory.Exists(networkPath))
{
    File.Copy(localPath, networkPath);
}
else
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(networkPath);
    File.Copy(localPath, alternativeNetworkPath);
}
```

and so now let's have a look at those paths in those variables and your problem should come right out.