# copy a file to shared folder on another computer

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying copy file to mapped network location.
If I try to do it manually everything is working OK.

By running following code I don't get any exceptions but I not get the code at the needed location.

```
     string _sharedLocation = @"C:\Users\pddd\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\system-tests";

     if (Directory.Exists(_sharedLocation) && File.Exists(@"c:\\Automation\\Tests\\Test1\\events.json"))
     {
         File.Copy(@"c:\\Automation\\Tests\\Test1\\events.json", Path.Combine(_sharedLocation, "events11.json"), true);
     }
```

Any suggestions with that issue.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not just catching an exception elsewhere? Does the target folder require authentication?

Comment: Have a look at [Copy file on a network shared drive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432213/copy-file-on-a-network-shared-drive) might give you a clue

Comment: Have a Look at
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801748/copying-local-file-to-network-shared-drive-issues
  or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432213/copy-file-on-a-network-shared-drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the `_SharedLocation` variable, it's on location: `"...\Windows\Network Shortcuts\..."`

I'm just guessing here, but are you tring to refer to a **shortcut to a network folder**, rather than a network folder?

This will never work:

```
File.Copy(myOriginalFile, "C:\...\MyShortcutToANetworkFolder\myFile.txt");
```

Why not? Because a shortcut is basically a *file*, not a *folder* (it's more complicated than that, but I'm keeping it simple for argument's sake). You cannot put a file (or anything else) into a shortcut. The only thing you can do with a shortcut is open it.

You need the actual network folder path.

This will work:

```
File.Copy(myOriginalFile, "\\myServer\myFolder1\myFolder2\myFile.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the target path `_sharedLocation` also refers to a local path, not a remote path.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you  sharedLocation path is not valid.

If you write @"c:\" it will refer your local  drive on which the code is running
so Please correct it

Comment: File.Copy should work whether that path points to a local or remote location. I think the issue comes from the face that the given filepath is a *folder shortcut*, not an actual *folder*.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**: Your shared Path refers to `C:` drive of same machine. Possibly you are referring to the shortcut of mapped network location.

```
 string _sharedLocation = @"C:\Users\pddd\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\system-tests";
```

It should be:

```
 string _sharedLocation = @"\\ComputerNetworkIdentity\SharedFolder\pddd\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\system-tests";
```

Shared computer can be located using `\\ComputerName`.
You must have **Write** permission on `shared folder`.

**Simple Way Locate A Shared Folder**:

1. Open `Run` dialog.
2. Type computer name with preceding backslash e.g. `\\ComputerNetworIdentity`
3. Locate the folders shared by the network computer.